# How to call script jquery when web page is showned?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

my process is when user click button print in first form then process is redirect to second page. Now when second page is showed i want to call jquery .How can i do , Please help. because i want to get html from second page.

this is my code in web

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { printForm() }, 3500);
        function printForm() {
            window.onload(function () {
                <%testMethod();%>
            });
    }
    });
</script>
```

this is my code in code behide

```
public void testMethod() {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            WebClient MyWebClient = new WebClient();
            string html = MyWebClient.DownloadString(Session["url"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

But the problem is testMethod is calling before scond page is show.  i want to do like window.print()

Comment: It appears that you don't understand that browser side javascript is completely separate from server side code.  You cannot mix/match the two.  Server-side code can be executed at page build time or upon some future Ajax request.  If you want to call something on your server from within the browser, then you need to issue an Ajax call from the web page and then hook up your `testMethod()` on the server to the Ajax request.

Comment: can you show me for example.

Comment: I'd suggest you do some research on how to do a browser ajax call to an asp.net app.  I don't know ASP myself, but I'm quite sure Microsoft has hundreds of examples documented since it is a major thing you would do with ASP.  The jQuery ajax call in the browser itself will look something like `$.get("/yourAjaxURL")`.

Comment: Before you even worry about ajax, stop and study the lifecycle of a web page

Comment: I don't want to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get jquery when other page loads, to do that with js only, you have to do something like this:
your_server ="some_server_name"

```
(function() {
        var jquery_scrpt = document.createElement('script'); jquery_scrpt.type = 'text/javascript'; jquery_scrpt.async = true;
        jquery_scrpt.src = 'https://' + your_server + '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(jquery_scrpt);
})();
```

this will add jquery dynamically to your page.Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank bro,But i want to call function when webpage(second form is rendered)

Comment: then you have to use ajax something like this :ajaxOptstest = {
 xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, //adds cookies, credentials
 url: "https://"+server_name+"/get_link/",
 dataType: 'json',
 crossDomain: true,//if cross
 data: data_vals,//if some data has to be passed
 success: function(resp){
  //do something on success
 },
};
jQuery.ajax(ajaxOptstest);

Comment: i don't want to use ajax. Are u know if i want to set a button auto onClick?

Comment: Now i try ajax but i get some error about this ("System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: stringHTMl.")

Comment: I am again not sure what you want , are you looking to trigger a click event of a button then check here http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: also for your issue check if you are setting your content type correctly,